# How to build a jar file of a project along with its dependencies from Maven pom.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I am trying to build a jar file from pom.xml with all its dependencies. I tried using **mvn package** but had issues accessing the dependent projects from the obtained jar.

I am trying to use the jar file obtained as an external library for another project.

Answer (score 0):

This should help (replace `Class.Name` with your `main` class):

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Class.Name</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it.